# How to work around proguard as it requires libs to run but says "duplicate" if they are provided

Tags: proguard

Having proguard issues since last update. (project and sdk, API 19)

First, com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
OK, visiting bin/proguard and unjarring obfuscated.jar I do see com/google/gson/JsonSerializer declared there. Why? It should be in the lib only.

**That is the crux of the question, why is Proguard copying in classes from the libs jars into ""?**

And what is "" anyways?  Progaurd fails saying the class is defined in gcm and "". What is ""? The class in only defined in libs/gcm.jar and nowhere else before I run the build.

Longer version, I add this to my proguard config:

```
  -libraryjars libs(!gson-2.1.jar,!RSAMobileSDK-1.01.jar;)
```

Can't see it does anything. Following other questions and answers on StackOverflow, I edit the android build.xml.

I do this: (because it turns out the -libraryjars in the config file is not being passed throug)

```
                    -libraryjars  ${project.target.classpath.value};libs/gson-2.1.jar
```

Still it says the file is multiply defined. If I could get proguard to ignore it then it would not be defined there. So, I try this in the build.xml:
Replace this:

```
                    -injars       ${project.all.classes.value}
```

with this:

```
                    -injars       bin\proguard\original.jar
```

What happens then?
It works!
So, why do I have to spefify these in the < proguard > element in the android build.xml, and how are I supposed to be able to do this with a config file?

```
                -injars       <b>bin\proguard\original.jar</b>

                -libraryjars  ${project.target.classpath.value}<b>;libs/gson-2.1.jar</b>
```

Comment: Can specify project.target.classpath.value explicitly in an input .properties file. Needed because what the Android build is assembling omits the jars in our libs folder.

Comment: Can also spec this in a .properties file so will not have to change the build.xml in android sdk tools folder. Still, feels like something is not right or being ignored.   project.all.classes.value=bin/proguard/original.jar

Comment: Above two comments are the work-around, so don't have to change the android tools build.xml. They still don't answer the question of why Proguard is doing the badness and also is ignoring the -library jars setting in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify additional input with -injars or -library jars in any configuration files; the build process already specifies these options for you. You'll only get lots of warnings about duplicate class files.

ProGuard indeed processes your own code together with the libraries. This is how it can significantly reduce the size of the application's code.

Comment: Thank you Eric. If I put this in a .properties file used by the build then I only need to change the -injars line in the android sdk\tools\ant\build.xml. project.target.classpath.value=libs/gcm.jar;libs/gson-2.1.jar;libs/RSAMobileSDK-1.01.jar;C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar  I still need to customize the -injars for it to succeed.

Comment: If I put nothing, then proguard fails. It says a class is multiply defined. The class is defined in gcm.jar but also I find it in obfuscated.jar. The message shows it is defined in "" and in gcm. Too bad "" doesn't tell me what jar. It definitely is NOT defined in my src directory; so "" is not correct in fact.